# Asana Python Connector - Get dataframe of all tasks for all projects

Tags: python-3.x, asana, asana-api, asana-connect

I am trying to get the information of all the tasks for all the projects in a certain workspace in python so i get generate some graphs. I am struggling to get any information on how to achieve this online or on https://github.com/Asana/python-asana. This is as far as i got.

```
import asana

personal_access_token = 'xxxxxxxxxxxx'

client = asana.Client.access_token(personal_access_token)
```

I would really appreciate some help on this.

Answer (score 0):

**Use this Code in Python 3:**

```
import asana
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

client = asana.Client.basic_auth('0/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')
me = client.users.me()
```

For Your Workspace Details:

```
workspace_id = me['workspaces'][0]['gid']
```

To find all projects name in workspace:

```
 proj= client.projects.find_all({'workspace': a_workspace_id,"opt_fields":{"this.name"}})
```